# AWS STS session token expired api request not retrying after refresh method called and updated credentials in javaScript

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-chime-sdk, amazon-chime

I am using **@Chime-sdk** and **@Angular-12** using **AWS STS** token, which one will expired after 15 minutes. After Expired STS token **AWS** call refresh method so I used **refresh()** method to call my back-end api for new token then I re-assign all credentials, till now it's working good.

But it can't retry last api or request after completed refresh method execution.
below attached my code:

```
this._aws.credentials.refresh = (() => {
      this.exampleApiService.getToken().toPromise()
        .then((response: any) => {
          this._aws.credentials.accessKeyId = response.accessKeyId;
          this._aws.credentials.secretAccessKey = response.secretAccessKey
          this._aws.credentials.sessionToken = response.sessionToken;
          this._aws.credentials.expireTime = response.expireTime;
          this._aws.credentials.expired = false;
          this.setChimeClient();

        }).catch(error => {
          console.log(error)
        });
    })
```

So How can i retry or recall my last last api call or request ?

Answer (score 0):

After trying multiple way, I get solution that's was to easy.

Chime pass a callBack function to refresh function so after credential set if we call, callBack function then Chime re-initiate last API call or process.

if we fail to generate refresh or new token then we can pass error in callBack function as param. below added example code.

```
this._aws.credentials.refresh = ((callback) => {
      this.exampleApiService.getToken().toPromise()
        .then((response: any) => {
          this._aws.credentials.accessKeyId = response.accessKeyId;
          this._aws.credentials.secretAccessKey = response.secretAccessKey
          this._aws.credentials.sessionToken = response.sessionToken;
          this._aws.credentials.expireTime = response.expireTime;
          this._aws.credentials.expired = false;
          this.setChimeClient();
          callback();
        }).catch(error => {
          console.log(error)
        });
    })
```